# How is a field's key (rather than value) obtained?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

In Drupal 7, I have a page content type that has a field called **group** (so the machine name is **field_group**).  The field is a **List (integer)** field type.

This field might have allowed values as follows:

```
0|Description 1
1|Description 2
2|Description 3
```

If I want to see the *value* of this field for the current page, the following code correctly works:

```
echo render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_group'));
```

If the key were set to 1 for this page, the above code would display the value "Description 2."

However, is there a way to instead get the *key* (e.g., 0, 1, 2, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the display in your content type "Manage Display" and ask to have the key and not the label :)
It's here : /admin/structure/types/manage/[your type]/display

Programmatically for a nude value as asked :

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_list'); 
$key = $items[0]['value'];
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68340/discussion-on-answer-by-seldell-in-drupal-7-how-is-a-fields-key-rather-than-v).