# How is a field's value (rather than its key) obtained?

Tags: theming, entities

In Drupal 7, I have a page content type that has a field called **group** (so the machine name is **field_group**).  The field is a **List (integer)** field type.

This field might have allowed values as follows:

```
0|Description 1
1|Description 2
2|Description 3
```

If I want to return the key of this field for the current page, the following code correctly works:

```
field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_group')[0]['value']
```

If the key were set to 1 for this page, the above code would return 1.

However, is there a way to instead return the associated *value* (e.g., "Description 1," "Description 2," etc.)?

I thought I had a way to return the value already, but I was told yesterday that my previous method was not a good way to get the value (or key) because my previous method may return extraneous data (such as unwanted HTML), when I really just want the raw key/value itself: [How is a field's key (rather than value) obtained?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249699/how-is-a-fields-key-rather-than-value-obtained)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you pass to `field_get_items()` the $node parameter. This should tell you that this function will return you a value stored in this Entity. The values of your field are stored in the field itself. You can get your options array as following.

```
$fieldData = field_info_field('field_group');
$options = $fieldData['settings']['allowed_values'];
```

Comment: I have verified that this works.  In this case, $options appears to be an array that holds the key => value of the requested field.

Comment: I take back the above comment to some extent.  While the code returns all allowed values, I need to return the value for the current page.

Comment: I think I understand now; you're saying to associate the key with the list in $options.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
$key = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_group')[0]['value'];    
$field = field_info_field('field_group');
$allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
$value = isset($allowed_values[$key]) ? $allowed_values[$key] : $key;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  It's very easy to understand because you laid out the process in each step until the $value was discovered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`field_view_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_value/7.x) for that.

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_group');
$value = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_group', $items[0]);
```